How come the performance of numpy.linalg.solve has changed drastically between versions 1.26.4 and 2.0.0?
I noticed that numpy.linalg.solve has vastly different performance since v2.0.0, on both Linux and Windows (haven't tested it on macOS). Basically, for reasonable matrices (up to about 1800x1800) the new versions are much faster (up to 10x faster of my Linux machine, I got even larger speedups on Windows), then for larger ones (up to about 8800x8800) the 1.26.4 version is faster, and for even larger ones the 2.0.0 version again becomes faster.
I wonder what happened? Is that due to an update of the underlying library?
If there were some modifications that impacted performance, I would have expected something to appear in the release notes, but there wasn't anything of the sort.
I ran a small benchmark using perfplot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def main():
    plot = False

    if not plot:
        out = perfplot.bench(
            setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n + 1, n),
            kernels=[lambda a: np.linalg.solve(a[1:], a[0])],
            n_range=[2**k for k in range(15)],
        )

        np.savetxt("n.txt", out.n_range)
        np.savetxt(f"timings_{np.__version__.replace(".", "_")}.txt", out.timings_s)
    else:
        n = np.loadtxt("n.txt")
        timings_1_26_4 = np.loadtxt("timings_1_26_4.txt")
        timings_2_0_0 = np.loadtxt("timings_2_0_0.txt")

        plt.plot(n, timings_1_26_4, label="1.26.4")
        plt.plot(n, timings_2_0_0, label="2.0.0")
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

        plt.plot(n, timings_1_26_4 / timings_2_0_0, label="1.26.4 / 2.0.0")
        plt.plot([0, 2**14], [1.0, 1.0])
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I ran it once with numpy==1.26.4 and once with numpy==2.0.0, and then a third time with plot=True to just plot.
Here is the overall result (x-axis is number of unknowns of the linear system, y-axis is time it takes to solve in seconds):
Performance comparison of numpy.linalg.solve between v1.26.4 and v2.0.0.
Here is a zoom up to n=200:
Zoom on the beginning of the plot.
And here is the ratio time for 1.26.4 / time for 2.0.0 (the horizontal line is y=1 to see which is faster):
Ratio of the timings for versions 1.26.4 and 2.0.0. When the curve is above the horizontal line, it means that v2.0.0 is faster.
In the last image, one can see that there is a peak at about n=35 where we have 10x.

"Is that due to an update of the underlying library?" Likely. It might be a good idea to open an issue. Note they will need a more reproducible example which does not rely on missing txt files ;) . You can also check if the library calls are the same and which version is used in both case. If you can isolate this is a library issue, then the issue needs to be posted directly on the target library (so your issue can be fixed faster). The target library used can change from one system to another and packaging matters (which might be the issue).

"It might be a good idea to open an issue." I thought so too but I wasn't sure it was actually an issue. "Note they will need a more reproducible example which does not rely on missing txt files ;)" well the script I included generates the txt files, I did it that way in order to plot both results in the same graph, because I couldn't think of a way to have two different versions of numpy installed in the same venv and accessible in the same script. If you have a way to achieve that I'd love to know about it :)

"You can also check if the library calls are the same and which version is used in both case." I did check the calls made on the Python side, and it looks to me like not much has changed in how numpy.linalg._linalg.solve is implemented, it still calls numpy.linalg._umath_linalg.solve which, if I understand correctly, calls LAPACK's gesv (that's what I understand from umath_linalg.cpp and also the numpy documentation). I'm not sure how I can check the LAPACK versions, do you have any pointers about that?

Ok I did not understand the purpose of the txt files and I do. This seems fine to me. Sorry for miss-understanding this. I wrote an answer for the other points ;)

What is the reference of your CPU by the way? (you can see it on Linux with grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | head -n 1)

No worries :)
In my original post I performed the tests on my work computer which has a 13th Gen Intel processor i7-13700H. Since then, I have also performed the same test on my personal computer which has an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H and the results are quite different. With the AMD proc the solve from 2.0 is faster until a system size of about 250x250, and then it's consistently slower. In addition, the peak speedup is only 2x for a 60x60 system.

I can reproduce the problem on my machine with an AMD Zen2 CPU (Ryzen 7 5700U).
With Numpy 1.26.4, low-level profiling with perf shows that most of the time is spent in libopenblas64_p-r0-0cf96a72.3.23.dev.so and more specifically two functions : dgemm_kernel_ZEN and inner_advanced_thread. Note inner_advanced_thread seems to just run a loop reading the same variable over and over so it is certainly a kind of spinning wait (it likely wait for the threads to complete).
With Numpy 2.1.1, perf shows that most of the time is spent in libscipy_openblas64_-ff651d7f.so and more specifically two functions : blas_thread_server, dgemm_kernel_HASWELL and dcopy_k_HASWELL. Note blas_thread_server seems to just run a loop running rdtsc and nop instructions so it certainly don't compute anything but just wait for threads to be ready, similar to inner_advanced_thread. Also note that the copy uses SSE instructions while my CPU supports AVX2 so it is likely sub-optimal.
We can see two important points:

The version of OpenBLAS changed from Numpy 1.26 to Numpy 2.1;
Numpy 1.26 calls dgemm BLAS functions optimized for my Zen CPU, while Numpy 2.1 calls one optimized for Intel Haswell CPUs likely less optimized for my Zen CPU. It also performs an expensive copy.

While the former point is expected when upgrading Numpy to a new major version (though it can impact performance), the later clearly seems like a packaging bug : the new linked BLAS library is not as optimized as the old one for the target platform.
We can see that the new OpenBLAS library mentions Scipy while the previous one does not. I think the problem is that Numpy now use the BLAS required by Scipy which is not as good as the version they packaged directly in Numpy (more specifically, the Scipy version looks like a generic one and the performance of BLAS libraries is highly dependent of the target CPU features used).

Update
With Numpy 2.0.0, dgemm_kernel_ZEN is called and the results seem close to the one of Numpy 2.1.1. Thus, the problem is finally not the architecture specialization. <-- However, I still see a quite expensive copy (dcopy_k_ZEN). Other minor functions still take more time than in version 1.26.4 (similar to version 2.1.1).--> Cores are clearly less well used in the version 2.0.0 and 2.1.1 than 1.26.4 possibly coming from a inefficient OpenMP scheduling (only set for the Scipy version). In fact, computation is nearly sequential with Numpy 2.0.0! The target library is still the one of Scipy. The use of the Scipy library is still the main difference between version 1.26.4 and 2.0.0.
If we use only one core, the version 1.26.4 and 2.0.0 are equally fast. This can be done with OMP_NUM_THREADS=1. It confirms the problem comes from the poor scalability of the Scipy version. That being said, tuning OMP_SCHEDULE has no visible effect (this typically happen if developers set the scheduling in the code, or the scheduling may not be the source of the scalability issue).

Notes
Note that there is an open issue for Intel CPUs having a big-little architecture (i.e. recent Intel CPUs). A similar issue might happen on other big-little CPUs (eg. AFAIK some Apple M1/M2/M3 CPUs)
Note you can also track the loaded libraries (including BLAS) with strace on Linux. More specifically, you can list the (sorted) dynamic dependencies with the following command:
strace -e trace=open,openat python your_script.py 2>&1 | grep -E "\"[^\"]*\.so\"" -o | sort -u

Another way (still on Linux) is just to set the environment variable LD_DEBUG=files.

So for me, on my personal computer (Ryzen 7 processor) I can see that dgemm_kernel_ZEN is being called for numpy versions 1.26.4 and 2.0.0, but for version 2.1.1 it's dgemm_kernel_HASWELL.
On my work computer (Intel i7), dgemm_kernel_PRESCOTT is being called for version 1.26.4, and dgemm_kernel_HASWELL for versions 2.0.0 and 2.1.1.
Do you think I should open an issue on the numpy repo?

The problem is finally a scalability issue directly related to the Scipy version. IDK exactly why (one need check the scheduling set in the code and also debug the code to know). I think you can open an issue on this (for the AMD CPU). Note that for recent Intel CPU, like your CPU, there is another bug linked in the answer (which is also apparently a multi-threading issue, but related to big-little cores).

You can try to change the number of thread to confirm the scalability issue or not. Using another BLAS library should help to fix this issue. On AMD CPUs, AMD advise people to use BLIS instead of OpenBLAS.
